# clearing input text area with dynamic input id's on button click - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although the question title gives an impression that I want to ask one question, but there are two problems I have facing at the moment.

I have gone through few similar questions on how to clear the input text area on button click, but most of them are for fixed input class or id's.

Problem 1: I am generating rows dynamically and and all the fields are being populated using JS thus the input ID's for all text boxes are different. Now if a user enter some number on "Apply to all" input field and click the button the same number should be set to all the rows which are added in the betslip.

Problem 2: After entering individual values in the betslip input boxes and if I click "clear all" button. It should clear all the inputs entered earlier in the bet slip.

Here is the HTML structure

```
<div id="bets">
  <div id="idNo1" class="bet gray2" name="singleBet">
    <div class="left">
      <p class="title">
        <p class="supermid">
          <input id="input_1" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="idNo2" class="bet gray2" name="singleBet">
    <div class="left">
      <p class="title">
        <p class="supermid">
          <input id="input_2" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="idNo3" class="bet gray2" name="singleBet">
    <div class="left">
      <p class="title">
        <p class="supermid">
          <input id="input_3" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS for adding element in the individual bets

```
function createSingleBetDiv(betInfo) {
    var id = betInfo.betType + '_' + betInfo.productId + '_' + betInfo.mpid,
        div = createDiv(id + '_div', 'singleBet', 'bet gray2'),
        a =  createA(null, null, null, 'right orange'),
        leftDiv = createDiv(null, null, 'left'),
        closeDiv = createDiv(null, null, 'icon_shut_bet'),
        singleBetNumber = ++document.getElementsByName('singleBet').length;

    // Info abt the bet
    $(leftDiv).append('<p class="title"><b><span class="bet_no">' + singleBetNumber + '</span>.&nbsp;' + betInfo['horseName'] + '</b></p>');
    var raceInfo = "";
    $("#raceInfo").contents().filter(function () {
        if (this.nodeType === 3) raceInfo = $(this).text() + ',&nbsp;' + betInfo['betTypeName'] + ' (' + betInfo['value'].toFixed(2) + ')';
    });
    $(leftDiv).append('<p class="title">' + raceInfo + '</p>');

    // Closing btn
    (function(id) {
        a.onclick=function() {
            removeSingleBet(id + '_div');
        };
    })(id);
    $(a).append(closeDiv);

    // Creating input field - This is where I am creating the input fields
    $(leftDiv).append('<p class="supermid"><input id="' + id + '_input\" type="text" class="betInput"></p>');

    // Creating WIN / PLACE checkbox selection
    $(leftDiv).append('<p><input id="' + id + '_checkbox\" type="checkbox"><b>' + winPlace + '</b></p>');

    // Append left part
    $(div).append(leftDiv);
    // Append right part
    $(div).append(a);
    // Appending div with data
    $.data(div, 'mapForBet', betInfo);

    return div;
}
```

HTML for Apply to all and Clear all button

```
<a href="javascript: applyToAllBetInput()"class="button apply orange">APPLY TO ALL <input type="text"> </a>

<a href="javascript: clearAllBetInput()" class="button clearall gray">CLEAR ALL</a>
```

JS where I need to implement those 2 functions

```
function applyToAllBetInput() {
    $('.apply').change(function() {
        $(this).prevAll().find('input[type=text]').val($(this).val());
    });
}

function clearAllBetInput() {
    $('.clearall').click(function() {
        $('div.bet').find('input').val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is wrong `var divId = $(this).attr('id').val(), inputId = divId.document.getElementById('input');`

Comment: Yes I am aware that is wrong. I can't select the input box with ID 'input' coz there isn't any!!!

Comment: `$(this).find('input').val('')` - Will be your input

Comment: Pseudo javascript protocols (javascript:) can cause errors in ie. Use <a href="#" onclick="applyToAllBetInput(); return false;">APPLY TO ALL</a> insted.

Comment: Have you tried: divId.document.getElementTagName('input'); insted of divId.document.getElementById('input'); ?

Comment: thanks for the pseudo protocol. I have removed the inline click handler. Yes, I had tried by fetching through ID instead of Name but it didn't work. I couldn't able to get all the dynamic input id's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is remove the inline event handlers from the links, like this...

```
<a href="#" class="button apply orange">APPLY TO ALL <input type="text"> </a>

<a href="#" class="button clearall gray">CLEAR ALL</a>
```

Then, assign the event handlers in your script...

```
$("a.button.apply").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    applyToAllBetInput($(this).find("input").val());
});

$("a.button.clearall").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    applyToAllBetInput("");
});
```

And this would apply the value to all inputs...

```
function applyToAllBetInput(value) {
    $("#bets div[name=singleBet] .supermid input:text").val(value);
}
```

If you pass a parameter into `applyToAllBetInput` and then set the inputs with that then you only need the one function, as they both do the same thing, but with different values.  Best to only have 1 bit of code if it's only doing 1 thing, then you only have to fix it once if things change in the future :)

Comment: One more thing. How can I wrap the 2 event handlers into 2 different functions and inside those functions I would call applyToAllBetInput. I don't want to create inline script.

Comment: Not sure I understand you.  The code I supplied does call 2 different functions, which then in turn call `applyToAllBetInput`

Comment: Hi again, Can you please help me out on this. I have restructured my code and I am using JS prototype feature. After changing my function Clear all button is working fine, but apply to all button doesn't work at all. I have updated my question with my latest HTML and JS code.

Comment: I've rolled the question back to the previous version.  Please don't change questions like that.  If you need to ask something else then create a new question.  This site is meant to be a catalogue of problems and fixes, and by changing the question like that you're basically deleting a problem that was fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several general suggestions I'd make before even starting to write the code. First, Why are you using longhand JavaScript when you have jQuery available? For example:

```
inputId = divId.document.getElementById('input');
```

should be simply:

```
inputId = $(inputId).find('input');
```

(or something along those lines--I'm not sure what you're after with that.)

Next, you're using inline click handlers. Instead, use event listeners:

```
<a href="javascript: applyToAllBetInput()" ...
```

Should be

```
$('a#my-id').click(function() { ... }
```

Finally, you can target all your inputs for clearing with a selector like this:

```
$('div.bet').find('input').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the id's i've given with your actual button/textarea ids (give ID's to your elements).

```
$('#txtApplyToAll').change(function() {
    $(this).prevAll().find('input[type=text]').val($(this).val());
 });

 $('#btnClearAll').click(function() {
    $('#txtApplyToAll').prevAll().find('input[type=text].val('');
});
```