# applying text input value to other empty text fields - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is in the continuation of another question I have asked earlier [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254589/clearing-input-text-area-with-dynamic-input-ids-on-button-click-jquery)

I am generating rows dynamically and and all the fields are being populated using JS thus the input ID's for all text boxes are different. Now if a user enter some number on "Apply to all" input field and click the button the same number should be set to all the rows which are added in the betslip.

HTML structure where I am adding rows dynamically

```
<div id="bets">
  <div id="idNo1" class="bet gray2" name="singleBet">
    <div class="left">
      <p class="title">
        <p class="supermid">
          <input id="input_1" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="idNo2" class="bet gray2" name="singleBet">
    <div class="left">
      <p class="title">
        <p class="supermid">
          <input id="input_2" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="idNo3" class="bet gray2" name="singleBet">
    <div class="left">
      <p class="title">
        <p class="supermid">
          <input id="input_3" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS for adding element in the individual bets

```
BetSlip.prototype.createSingleBetDiv = function(Bet) {

    var id = Bet.betType + '_' + Bet.productId + '_' + Bet.mpid,
        divId = id + '_div';

    // If such bet already exists
    if (typeof document.betSlip.singleDivs[divId] == "undefined") {
        var div = element.create('div'),
            a = element.create('a'),
            leftDiv = element.create('div'),
            closeDiv = element.create('div'),
            singleBetNumber = ++document.getElementsByName('singleBet').length;

        element.setId(div, divId);
        element.setName(div, 'singleBet');
        element.setClassName(div, 'bet gray2');
        element.setClassName(a, 'right orange');
        element.setClassName(leftDiv, 'left');
        element.setClassName(closeDiv, 'icon_shut_bet');

        // Info abt the bet
        $(leftDiv).append('<p class="title"><b><span class="bet_no">' + singleBetNumber + '</span>.&nbsp;' + Bet['horseName'] + '</b></p>');
        var raceInfo = "";
        $("#raceInfo").contents().filter(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === 3) raceInfo = $(this).text() + ',&nbsp;' + Bet['betTypeName'] + ' (' + Bet['value'].toFixed(2) + ')';
        });
        $(leftDiv).append('<p class="title">' + raceInfo + '</p>');

        // Closing btn
        (function(id) {
            a.onclick=function() {document.betSlip.removeSingleBet(divId);};
        })(id);
        $(a).append(closeDiv);

        // Creating input field
        $(leftDiv).append('<p class="supermid"><input id="' + id + '_input\" type="text"></p>');

        // Creating WIN / PLACE checkbox selection
        $(leftDiv).append('<p><input id="' + id + '_checkbox\" type="checkbox"><b>' + winPlace + '</b></p>');

        // Append left part
        $(div).append(leftDiv);
        // Append right part
        $(div).append(a);
        // Appending div with data
        $.data(div, 'Bet', Bet);

        // Add div to the bet slip map
        document.betSlip.singleDivs[divId] = div;

        return div;
    }
    else {
        $("#betSlipError").show();
        $("#betSlipError").html(sameBet);
        return null;
    }
}
```

HTML for applyTOall button

```
<a onclick="document.betSlip.applyToAll(event)" class="button apply orange">APPLY TO ALL <input type="text"> </a>
```

JS for applyToall function

```
BetSlip.prototype.applyToAll = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.betSlip.applyToAllBetInput($(this).find("input").val());
}

BetSlip.prototype.applyToAllBetInput = function(value) {
    $("#bets div[name=singleBet] .supermid input:text").val(value);
}
```

Comment: @Archer here is the new question I have created in lieu with my previous question asked.

Comment: create a fiddle please?

Comment: @user1708762 I have added link to the live site.

Comment: your HTML is missing alot of closing tags, could be giving unexpected behaviour..

Comment: @JF The first HTML block in my code is generated dynamically with proper closing tag. I just put the skeleton to give a general overview. Sorry if I missed closing the paragraph tags :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this way:

```
$('yourbutton').on('click', function(){
   var applyVal = $('applyvalinput').val();
   $('#bets').find('[id^="input"][type="text"]').val(applyVal);
});//^------finds the inputs in this specific div.
```

---

Click your button and cache the value of your *apply to all* input val and check for the inputs which has the ids started *`[id^="input"]`* by the term **input** and it applies the value to each text input.